# Arrays en checkbox value php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, array, checkbox

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th data-toggle="true"> Usuario </th>
  <?php 
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM etapas_lab WHERE id_cliente = '$id_us'"; 
        $ejecutar_consulta = $conexion->query($consulta); 
        $nomx = array();
        while ($registro = $ejecutar_consulta->fetch_assoc()){ 
         $nom = utf8_encode($registro["nombre"]);
         $nomx[] = $registro["id"];
         echo '<th>'.$nom.' </th>';
        } 
  ?>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<?php 
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id_cliente = '$id_us'"; 
    $ejecutar_consulta = $conexion->query($consulta);                                       
     while ($registro = $ejecutar_consulta->fetch_assoc()){ 
      $nom_user = utf8_encode($registro["nombres"]);
      $ape_user = utf8_encode($registro['apellidos']);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$nom_user.' '.$ape_user.' </td>';

    $arr_length = count($nomx); 

    for($i=0;$i<$arr_length;$i++){ 

    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" name="permiso[]" 
    data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" data-size="small" 
    value='--> AQUI DEBEN IR LOS ARRAYS <--' /> </td>';

    }                                                                           
echo '</tr>';   

} 
?>

</tbody>
```

Lo que hace la primera parte del codigo (en el thead), llama a nombres de procesos que son listados en el head de la tabla html.
La segunda parte, cuenta la cantidad de registros (en el for) de mi BD y pone un ckeckbox por cada registro a cada usuario creado en la BD. En la siguiente imagen, se ve como es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, mi problema radica en como enviar el id de cada proceso (colado, troquelado, etc) junto con el id del usuario a traves del value del checkbox cuando se clickee el checkbox (estoy usando js-switch).
Cabe señalar que el id del proceso, proviene de la primera consulta y el id del usuario de la segunda consulta.
Como siempre, agradecido de cualquier ayuda y/u orientacion al respecto.
Saludos a todos.

Comment: Puedes usar otros atributos como `data-usuario` y `data-proceso`

Comment: O, si quieres aprovechar la etiqueta `value`, puedes hacer algo así: `value='valor1|valor2|valor3|valor4'` y luego hacer un  `explode` usando el separador `|`, de ese modo obtendrás un array con cada uno de los valores. Era la alternativa perfecta, antes de que existiera `data`, y todavía hoy es totalmente válida.

Comment: @alanfcm gracias por tu respuesta, pero como aplico esos atributos, al hacerlo y probar me sale array en el data-proceso ($nomx[] = $registro["id"];). agradeceria, me pudieses orientar un poco mas. muchas gracias,

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por responder. al igual que la info del comentario anterior, tanto value (con tu idea) y data- (con el comentario anterior), me muestra Array en el $nomx[] = $registro["id"]; que es el arra y que viene de la primera consulta, y ademas aprovecho de preguntar, como uso o saco ese array ($nomx[]) fuera del while y usarlo en el for de abajo? gracias por tu ayuda e informacion.

Comment: Si el array se está construyendo bien, puedes escribir la segunda parte del código así: **`foreach($nomx as $item){ 
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" name="permiso[]" 
    data-color="#99d683" data-secondary-color="#f96262" data-size="small" 
    value="'.$item.'" /> </td>';
}`**

Comment: @A.Cedano perfecto.. aplique tu ejemplo con atirbuto data y ha funcionado de maravillas. millon de gracias y que tengas una buena semana.

Comment: Lo he puesto como respuesta, para que la cuestión quede zanjada y por si puede servir a otros. Me alegro de que te haya servido.

Comment: @A.Cedano me parece genial estimado. Nuevamente gracias por la ayuda. saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el array se está construyendo bien, puedes escribir la segunda parte del código así:

```
foreach($nomx as $item){
    echo '<td>
              <input type="checkbox" class="js-switch" name="permiso[]" 
                     data-color="#99d683" 
                     data-secondary-color="#f96262" 
                     data-size="small" value="'.$item.'" />
          </td>'; 
}
```